# Get ip address of interface eth0

Tags: lua

How can i find out the ip address of eth0 with lua?
My attempt does look like this:

```
system = require "system"
ip = system._execute("ifconfig eth0 | grep -i 'inet addr:'")
print (ip)
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: If you have `FFI` available you can directly bind into any relevant library without writing C<->Lua glue.

Comment: What is `FFI`, for what does it stand for?

Comment: http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html

Answer (score 1):

"better way" may be subjective, but I guess I'd (personally) prefer to io.popen("ifconfig etho") and process the text coming back from that like a text file, instead of relying on grep.